# What are the differences between CAS protocol and SAML protocol?

Tags: saml, cas

If both protocol are both used to provide SSO, what are the reason to use one over another? Can you please list out some major difference between them which make them suitable for different tasks and situations?

Note: I'm not talking about the CAS software, I'm talking about the CAS protocol.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proprietary protocol developed exclusively for the CAS server.

However:

"Even if the primary goal of the CAS server is to implement the CAS protocol, other protocols are also supported as extensions:

```
OpenID
OAuth
SAML"
```

Because the CAS protocol is proprietary, it is not supported by IDP's e.g. Azure AD, ADFS, Auth0 etc.

So if all you want to do is use the CAS protocol to talk to the CAS server, that will work.

If however, you want to talk to another IDP, you cannot use the CAS protocol to do this. You would have to use one of the protocol extensions as above.

It is also possible to write a [bridging protocol](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-cas-server). This way you can continue to use the CAS protocol but the IDP sees it as OpenID Connect

So if in the CAS world, use the CAS protocol but if you need to use other IDP, stick to the standard three protocols.

Comment: 1) Do you mean: This (**CAS protocol**) is a proprietary protocol developed exclusively for CAS (**CAS server**)?

Comment: 2) Do you mean: Because it (**CAS protocol**) is proprietary, it is not supported by IDP's e.g. Azure AD, ADFS, Auth0 etc.?

Comment: 3) What do you mean by bridging protocol? Can you please explain why we would want to do that?

Comment: Overall, do you mean **CAS protocol is only supported by CAS server, while other protocols like OpenID, OAuth and SAML are supported by different IDP. So if I am already CAS server or don't need to use other IDP, then I can just use CAS protocol and server; but if I need to work with other IDP, then CAS protocol cannot do that**?

Comment: Updated answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

**[SAML (Security Assertion Markup Language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)** as well as **[CAS (Central Authentication Service)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service)** are **[Single Sign On (SSO) protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)** (or *standards*) used to manage access control decision.

---

**SAML** stands for *Security Assertion Markup Language* (pronounced SAM-el) and it is an open *standard* for exchanging authentication and authorization data between parties, in particular, between an **IdP** (*Identity Provider*), ie. SaaS company that stores usernames and passwords, and a **SP** (*Service Provider*) ie. your website or service.

SAML is an XML-based markup language *standard* for security assertions. It contains: a set of XML-based protocol messages, a set of protocol message bindings and a set of profiles (utilizing all of the above).

In simple words, SAML is an XML framework (*standard*) for SSO (Single Sign On) which can be used by various applications to authenticate ("you are, who you are saying you are") or authorize access ("you have access to this application part").

---

**CAS**, on the other hand, stands for **Central Authentication Service** and is similarly a single sign-on, ticket-based *protocol standard* or *framework*. Its purpose is to permit a user to access multiple applications while providing their credentials (such as user id and password) only once.

The name CAS also refers to a software package (called [Apereo CAS](https://apereo.github.io/cas/)) that implements this protocol (it's worth to note that even if the primary goal of the CAS server is to implement the CAS protocol, other protocols are also supported as extensions, ie. Apereo CAS Server also contains ability to implement SAML).

The key concepts with CAS are: The **TGT** (*Ticket Granting Ticket*), stored in the **TGC** cookie, represents a SSO session for a user, and the **ST** (*Service Ticket*) - transmitted as a GET parameter in urls - stands for the access granted by the CAS server to the CASified application for a specific user.

One of the most powerful feature of the CAS protocol is the ability for a CAS service to act as a proxy for another CAS service, transmitting the user identity.

---

**Special considerations when choosing SAML or CAS:**

*SAML:*

- Registration between SP and IDP is mandatory, can be done with public
  metadata exchange (you need to agree beforehand what metatags will be sent between SP and IDP)
- XML messages can be signed and/or encrypted with the help of
  asymmetric keys (public keys published in metadata)

*CAS:*

- No obligation to declare CAS clients in CAS server (open mode)
- Trust between CAS client and CAS server relies on CAS server
  certificate validation

---

**Conclusion:**
(as per [this](https://ldapcon.org/2017/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/16_Cl%C3%A9ment-Oudot_PRE_LDAPCon2017_SSO-1.pdf) presentation):

*SAML:* complex protocol, very often used for SaaS authentication, good security, well established

*CAS:* simple protocol, no strong security, fits internal usage